# Open multiple text files for modification efficiently for unspecified number of files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list similar to following:

```
MyList = [[11, 9, 7, 7, 8, 'FileA.data'], 
          [13, 9, 8, 6, 8, 'FileB.data'], 
          [13, 11, 8, 7, 7, 'FileC.data']]
```

What I'd like to do is to create and open FileA.data, FileB.data and FileC.data for appending and then add to those files corresponding numbers, so FileA.data would have a line of text:

11   9   7   7   8

FileB.data would have:

13   9   8   6   8

and so on.

The thing is that during the next iteration I'll have different numbers, which I'd like to add to their corresponding files again. I've written the following code that works more or less as I inten (I want to add index numbers to each line and add some other embellishments but that's outside the scope of the question so I'll omit it):

```
for element in MyList:
   file = open(element[-1],'a+')
   for data in element[:-1]:
       file.write(str(data)+' ')
   file.write('\n')
   file.close()
### now update MyList and go back to beginning.
```

What bothers me is that opening each file for writing, then closing and repeating it potentially thousands of times doesn't strike me as efficient. What I'd like to ask: is there a solution that would allow me to open those files for edit once, run the append loop enough times, and then close those files all at once? something akin to:

```
file1 = open(FileA.data, 'a+')
file2 = open(FileB.data, 'a+')
file3 = open(FileC.data, 'a+')
### update and add data to fileA, fileB, fileC multiple times
file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
```

The end result would have files with multiple lines - e.g.

FileA.data:

```
11   9   7   7   8
3   2   6   5   15
       ...
1   2   3   5   1
```

Also, I'd like it to be universal - so that it works with more or less than 3 files. Also, I'd like you to keep in mind that I'm relatively a beginner. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59395011/edit) to include the code you've tried so far in your solution attempts. If you *haven't* written anything yet, go write some! Askers are expected to have put at least *some* effort into researching a solution themselves before asking here, and *showing* that effort directly in the question. Can't expect other people to put in the time and effort you aren't. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for data in MyList:
    with open(data[-1], "w+") as fp:
        fp.write(" ".join(data[:-1]))
```

This should get the job done. Here, you loop through your list such that, for each sub-list, you treat the last element as the file-name desired and execute the desired operation (i.e. you open the [File](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) - create it if it doesn't already exist - and then write your data).

Make sure you use the `with` block wherever you can; it's syntactic sugar for opening/closing resources like files, i.e. once you come out of the block, the File is closed on your behalf. This is an idiomatic way to handle resources that need to be `.close()`'d.